# Cannot open SQL editor on macOS High Sierra

Tags: macos, mysql-workbench

Since updating to macOS High Sierra, I have not been able to open the SQL Editor on MySQL Workbench.

When I try to connect to the database, as usual, I'm given the following prompt: 
[image]

However, after a few seconds, it simply disappears. I'm given no error or any indication from the application that anything went wrong. I've tried redownloading the application, but I'm getting the same result.

edit:
I tried using previous versions of Workbench, and it works perfectly on version 2.6.5.

Comment: That's a bummer. There was already trouble with macOS Sierra, because Apple changed thing so that developers where forced to build their apps with the latest XCode (which in turn required new releases). A pain if that hits you outside your normal release cycles. Please [file a bug report](http://bugs.mysql.com) for that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Version **6.1.7** has a disappearing grid bug on subsequent queries, which was fixed in **6.2.^** But **6.2** doesn't work on High Sierra as well.

I found that **6.0.8** works fine on Hight Sierra. Here is the link to archived versions: [MySQL Workbench Versions](https://downloads.mysql.com/archives/workbench/)

(It is a bit slow if you load more than 1000 results at a time, so keep the default limit. You will also lose quick action buttons as it came in 6.2)

Comment: ssh connection not working on 6.1.7. Did you check ssh connection in version 6.0.8. Is it working?

Comment: @Aravi No I have not. For connection being refused, also check your security groups :)

Answer (score 1):

This is definitely a problem on MySQL's end, so all we can do is wait until an update comes out for the new OS.

I have filed a bug report [here](https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=86649/%22here%22) if anyone is interested in following it.

Answer (score 1):

Version 6.3.10 has been released. Fixed a bug in MacOS HighSierra.

[Download here](https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/file/?id=474219)

Answer (score 0):

Downgrading to [version 6.1.7](https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=87862) appears to be the current work around. Thanks to Daniel Romero for finding this. Also [this bug report](https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=87862) appears to be the currently active one if you want to subscribe.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with MySQL Workbench and SQL Pro Studio. The query is working fine but it doesn't show any results. [Sequel Pro (Free)](https://www.sequelpro.com/) and Navicat Premium (Paid and Expensive) are working fine.