# MySQL Workbench (6.3.9) is not compatible with MacOS High Sierra?

Tags: macos, mysql-workbench, macos-high-sierra

Today morning I upgraded my MacBook to `High Sierra (Version 10.13)`

Now, my `MySQL workbench (6.3.9)` is behaving weirdly after this OS update...

1) When opened a fresh and executed simple select statement, workbench does not show results grid after query is executed.

2) When same/another select query is executed again, nothing comes up. Only workbench shows that query is being executed and shows in-progress wheel on tab...

Anybody witnessed this?

P.S.: I can query successfully using another laptop not having High Sierra and my DB is well up and running.

Comment: It's not MySQL Workbench that breaks things, but the OS update. How can an OS update so badly influence applications that ran before nicely?

Comment: I've found that this issue has already been reported to MySQL Workbench team but it is marked _S3 (Non-critical)_ unfortunately. [Here](https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=87714) is the bug report.

Comment: @kizanlik: Yes, I saw that link. not sure if there is any process which can mark this as "Critical"

Comment: @MikeLischke I disagree in this case. The reliability of Workbench is a joke around my office - the thing crashes if you look at it wrong on every platform we've tried.

Comment: Here is a [different link](https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=87862&thanks=sub) to the bug which is marked as S1 (Critical). I would be sure to click the "affects me" button to hopefully get it prioritized.

Comment: @JacobSee It's not alway MySQL Workbench's blame. There's a reason why currently many (even big) companies warn about macOS High Sierra and that people should wait for a few weeks before upgrading.

Comment: @AkshayLokur I have the same problem... I am now using NetBeans to do some queries in a graphical environmen... it's been nice so far. Maybe you might want to try it...

Comment: @AkshayLokur I am trying https://dbeaver.jkiss.org/ which so far looks really promising... check it out. NetBeans turned out to be a little to limited for my needs in MySQL work.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Use last version 6.3.10.
It works fine for me at High Sierra
https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/file/?id=474219

Comment: Finally, it's fixed and released!

Answer (score 28):

Had the same issue. Downgraded to 6.1.7. Seems to work fine.

https://dev.mysql.com/get/Downloads/MySQLGUITools/mysql-workbench-community-6.1.7-osx-i686.dmg

Comment: I have downgraded to this version but still have the same issue when running queries (Although oddly it works fine if you right click on a table and select 2000 rows).

Comment: Cannot alter tables in High Sierra on MySQL Workbench 6.1.7

Answer (score 15):

I had the same problem compatibility High Sierra / Mysql Wrokbench 6.3.9

If you use the link from kizanlik where bug is reported

https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=87714

you will find a new dmg (October 4,)
It works for me

Comment: For quick download:
https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/0B2fTesDcrHzVRGVFWEdILWpuaEE

Comment: Someone made a quick fix for the problem and posted it. It works! So if you don't have the time for the official fix, use this.

Answer (score 6):

Yes, MySQL WorkBench 6.1.7 is working on High Sierra, but [here is the right link.](https://dev.mysql.com/get/Downloads/MySQLGUITools/mysql-workbench-community-6.1.7-osx-i686.dmg)

Comment: It works but not 100% properly. I cannot alter tables in High Sierra on MySQL Workbench 6.1.7

Answer (score 3):

As I mentioned here: [Cannot open SQL editor on macOS High Sierra](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44469610/cannot-open-sql-editor-on-macos-high-sierra)

Version **6.1.7** has a disappearing grid bug on subsequent queries, which was fixed in **6.2.^** But **6.2** doesn't work on High Sierra as well.

I found that **6.0.8** works fine on Hight Sierra. Here is the link to archived versions: [MySQL Workbench Versions](https://downloads.mysql.com/archives/workbench/)

Answer (score 0):

MySQL WorkBench 6.1.7 is work well on High Sierra